# GAE ndb.JsonProperty() default list

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have the following set up. Why does the default list property of the JsonProperty retain the previous values assigned to it in other entities. Am I missing something?

```
class Item(ndb.Model):
    foo = ndb.JsonProperty(default=[])

    def add_to_foo(self, value):
        self.foo.append(value)
        return

item1 = Item()
item1.add_to_foo('one')
item1.put()

item2 = Item()
item2.add_to_foo('two')
item2.put()

print item2.foo  # prints out ['one', 'two']
```

Why does it print out ['one', 'two']? I only gave it 'two'. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, this is the expected behavior -- but why is a bit tricky to explain.  The problem is that you are passing a `list` instance to the `JsonProperty` intializer.  This list is effectively `global`.  So, anytime you get the "default" `foo`, you'll be getting the global instance -- and appending to it will append to it everywhere.

The point here is **don't use mutable arguments as default values**.  You're better off re-writing `add_to_foo`:

```
def add_to_foo(self, value):
    if self.foo:
        self.foo.append(value)
    else:
        self.foo = [value]
```

<sup>Note that this gets even a bit more interesting if you `.get` one of your items back out of the datastore.  Assuming the entity wasn't cached locally, at that point, they won't have a reference to the global list -- only a copy of the list's state when it was `.put`.</sup>